# What strategy is the most effective to beat the Volcano in Cthulhu Saves the World?

Tags: cthulhu-saves-the-world

I'm up to Chapter 7 (Volcano! or something) in the volcano, and finding it very difficult. Most of the monsters have > 1000 HP and take forever to knock down. The T-Rexes and the Kaboomsters manage to take off 150HP~ per character in my party on some turns. Everyone in my party is level 24 (Paws is 25), and I've managed to exhaust all the battles in each dungeon so far.

What tactics should I employ so that I don't die so much? I use Snowstorm and Flood to attempt to hit a lot of them, and I can take out the lower HP mobs (Salamanders, Hellhounds, etc) but the T-Rexes, Golems, and Kaboomsters never go down fast enough.

Am I missing something big?

EDIT: I watched a Let's Play of a guy in the same place. He not only did tons more damage, but seemed to have a million weapons and armour pieces more. Did I miss something huge?

EDIT2: I can't even escape without dying multiple times. I just get put against multiple enemies (Raptors, Kaboomsters, Pyromummies, or T-Rexes) and cannot survive without using up all of my potions.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to an easier area and continue to farm enemies by going to the menu and selecting "Fight" as many times as you need to in order to level up.

This will manually kick off a fight, even if you've exhausted the random battles for an area.